# how to output the second line in a multi-line file

Tags: perl

I have a big file with repeated lines as follows:

```
@UUSM
ABCDEADARFA
+------qqq
!2wqeqs6777
```

I will like to output the all the 'second line' in the file. I have the following code snipped for doing this, but it's not working as expected. Lines 1, 3 and 4 are in the output instead.

```
open(IN,"<", "file1.txt") || die "cannot open input file:$!";
while (<IN>) {
$line = $line . $_;
if ($line =~ /^\@/) { 
    <IN>;
    #next;
    my $line = $line; 
    }
}
print "$line";
```

Please help!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you hope to accomplish with `my $line = $line`?

Comment: @TLP: confusion — that's all.  :D To user27976: Please clarify your question (including the title) to explain what you want more accurately.  Are you after line numbers 2N+2 (for integral N starting at 0) or are you after 'the line after a line starting with `@`' (which raises the question of what should happen if two consecutive lines start with `@`).  Or something else?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, but what is the intent, is what I wonder. Unless its just static, randomly pressed keys, he must have had some purpose for putting it there. :) Trying to better understand the workings of the newbie mind here.

Comment: @TLP: See the dissection of the code in my answer.  My best guess is that, like the commented out `#next;`, it is part of an attempt to handle the problem without really knowing what's going on.  Most of the trouble is in the `$line = $line . $_;` line; the string concatenation should not be executed there before the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
open(IN,"<", "file1.txt") || die "cannot open input file:$!";
my $lines = "";

while (<IN>) {
 if ($. % 4 == 2) $lines .= $_;
}

print "$lines";
```

Comment: Why stash all the lines into a single big string?  It can certainly be done, but grinds to a halt if the input file is gigabytes in size.

Comment: I just get it from origin sample, ofcose prefer print $_ from loop. But may author wish do somethink with $links after?

Comment: Actually, the original code is confused, adding `$_` to `$line` before it looks at what is in (the first segment of) `$line`.  It is, in fact, so confused as to be ... dreadful?  But I'll allow that the original code does accumulate the data — though the stated purpose is just to print the 'second lines' which seem to be the 'line after a line starting with `@`', though even that isn't entirely clear in the question and its code.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne '$at = $. if /^\@/; print if $. - 1 == $at' file1.txt
```

Written out longhand, the above is equivalent to

```
open my $fh, "<", "file1.txt";

my $at_line = 0;
while (<$fh>) {
    if (/^\@/) {
      $at_line = $.;
    }
    else {
      print if $. - 1 == $at_line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you are asking is how to print the line that comes after a line that begins with `@`:

```
perl -ne 'if (/^\@/) { print scalar <> }' file1.txt
```

This says, "If the line begins with `@`, then print the next line. Do this for all the files in the argument list." The `scalar` function is used here to impose a scalar context on the file handle, so that it does not print the whole file. By default `print` has a list context for its arguments.

If you actually want to print the second line in the file, well, that's even easier. Here's a few examples:

Using the line number `$.` variable, printing if it equals line number 2.

```
perl -ne '$. == 2 and print, close ARGV' yourfile.txt
```

Note that if you have multiple files, you must close the ARGV file handle to reset the counter `$.`. Note also the use of the lower precedence operator `and` will force `print` and `close` to both be bound to the conditional.

Using regular logic.

```
perl -ne 'print scalar <>; close ARGV;'
perl -pe '$_ = <>; close ARGV;'
```

Both of these uses a short-circuit feature by closing the ARGV file handle when the second line is printed. If you should want to print every other line of a file, both these will do that if you remove the `close` statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want lines 2, 6, 10 printed, then:

```
while (<>)
{
    print if $. % 4 == 2;
}
```

Where `$.` is the current line number — and I didn't spend the time opening and closing the file.  That might be:

```
{
    my $file = "file1.txt";
    open my $in, "<", $file or die "cannot open input file $file: $!";
    while (<$in>)
    {
        print if $. % 4 == 2;
    }
}
```

This uses the modern preferred form of file handle (a *lexical* file handle), and the braces around the construct mean the file handle is closed automatically.  The name of the file that couldn't be opened is included in the error message; the `or` operator is used so the precedence is correct (the parentheses and `||` in the original were fine too and could be used here, but conventionally are not).

If you want the line after a line starting with `@` printed, you have to organize things differently.

```
my $print_next = 0;
while (<>)
{
    if ($print_next)
    {
        print $_;
        $print_next = 0;
    }
    elsif (m/^@/)
    {
        $print_next = 1;
    }
}
```

#### Dissecting the code in the question

The original version of the code in the question was (line numbers added for convenience):

```
 1   open(IN,"<", "file1.txt") || die "cannot open input file:$!";
 2   while (<IN>) {
 3   $line = $line . $_;
 4   if ($line =~ /^\@/) {
 5       <IN>;
 6       #next;
 7       my $line = $line;
 8       }
 9   }
10   print "$line";
```

Discussion of each line:

1. OK, though it doesn't use a lexical file handle or report which file could not be opened.
2. OK.
3. Premature and misguided.  This adds the current line to the variable `$line` before any analysis is done.  If it was desirable, it could be written `$line .= $_;`
4. Suggests that the correct description for the desired output is not 'the second lines' but 'the line after a line starting with `@`.  Note that since there is no multi-line modifier on the regex, this will always match only the first line segment in the variable `$line`.  Because of the premature concatenation, it will match on each line (because the first line of data starts with `@`), executing the code in lines 5-8.
5. Reads another line into `$_`.  It doesn't test for EOF, but that's harmless.
6. Comment line; no significance except to suggest some confusion.
7. `my $line = $line;` is a self-assignment to a new variable hiding the outer `$line`...mainly, this is *weird* and to a lesser extent it is a no-op.  You are not using `use strict;` and `use warnings;` because you would have warnings if you did.  Perl experts use `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to make sure they haven't made silly mistakes; novices should use them for the same reason.
8. Of itself, OK.  However, the code in the condition has not really done very much.  It skips the second line in the file; it will later skip the fourth, the sixth, the eighth, etc.
9. OK.
10. OK, but...if you're only interested in printing the lines after the line starting `@`, or only interested in printing the line numbers 2N+2 for integral N, then there is no need to build up the entire string in memory before printing each line.  It will be simpler to print each line that needs printing as it is found.

Comment: Many thanks Dmitry and Jonathan. I apologise for the confusion in the way I asked the questions. I got the desired results using the codes from the two you. I really appreciate the comments and explanations.